# Nodejs ou solução em flash para streaming de video ao vivo!

Tags: html5, node.js, flash, streaming, webrtc

Olá, já postei diversas mensagens sobre o assunto mas ainda não consegui uma solução definitiva, preciso fazer **streaming** de vídeo ao vivo e que o player que vai transmitir rode em qualquer navegador (possivelmente html5), já tentei **WebRTC** e funciona bem, mas só roda no chrome e no firefox, nada do **internet explorer**...Agora estou tentando usar o **NodeJs** e tudo funcionam bem no meu node local (localhost/127.0.0.1) mas quando vou enviar os dados para o servidor nada de conectar no meu ip, eu uso a Vivo Internet em SP e eles liberam 2 portas a **51005** e a **14330**, com a 51005 quando vou conectar recebo o erro 401 - Não autorizado, e a 14330 o problema é que aparece a mensagem "not implemented" quando conecto no navegador, essa porta 14330 eu li que é só pra acesso torrent e não conecta servidores, agora estou atrás de uma solução que rode nos 3 navegadores (ie, chrome e firefox) ou alguma maneira de rodar o nodejs na **Vivo Internet**!!!

**Alguém ???**

Aceito uma sugestão em **Flash** (action script) também, não encontrei nada sobre streaming de vídeo no flash...

Comment: Quanto a streaming em fash, apesar das soluções abertas, me parece que os sites mais "profissionais" (com dinheiro) usam a solução da própria Adobe (claro!!) http://www.adobe.com/products/adobe-media-server-standard.html | Ainda tem o http://www.red5.org/ (nao conheço, mas pode ser um bom serviço) | html5 é uma questão complicada, a Micro$oft ganha bilhões e só agora resolveu  __começar__ a suportar o básico do HTML5. A solução para o IE é usar Flash mesmo, eu acho... mas você pode deixar com WebRTC já que funfa bem e forçar os usuarios a usar um navegador suportado.

Answer (score 1):

Como tudo na vida, é uma questão de escolha.

Se você quer realmente suportar o IE, não adianta usar Node, afinal seu problema não está no backend e sim no front.

Em uma resposta bem curta, a única maneira de lidar com a situação é usando Flash + algum media server. Pode ser o Red5 ou AMS.

Minha sugestão é dar uma olhada aqui: http://influxis.com/ que provavelmente é o melhor serviço que você pode ter por um preço razoável.

Answer (score 0):

Se você precisa expor na internet um serviço que roda em uma máquina da sua rede local, sugiro utilizar alguma coisa como o https://pagekite.net/

"PageKite makes local websites or SSH servers publicly accessible in mere seconds, and works with any computer and any Internet connection.
It's also 100% Open Source."

Simples assim:

```
$ curl -s https://pagekite.net/pk/ |sudo bash
$ pagekite.py 80 seunome.pagekite.me
```

Acesse http://seunome.pagekite.me/ de qualquer lugar =)